# Is it possible to add any arbitrary application as a shortcut in the Car Home app?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, samsung-nexus-s

In the [Google Car Home](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.google.android.carhome) app, when I click "Add Shortcut" on one of the available Car Home icons, and then select "Other applications", I am only presented with two options:

- Blast Monkeys
- Launcher

Why just these two? Do apps have to register themselves specially to be available here? I know that is true for the "Car Applications" list, but I wouldn't think that were true for "Other applications". It's hard to imagine that Blast Monkeys (a game) would be car mode compatible.

Should I be able to add any app as a shortcut? Or should I just find another car mode app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I rebooted my phone and the problem went away (I can now see and choose from all installed apps). Must be a a bug.

Answer (score 1):

On my Nexus One (2.3.4) the “Other Applications” list has the usual list of everything.